# Firestore VPCSC_CHECK_FAILED when trying to login using firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vpn, google-identity-toolkit

We use firebase for authentication. When users signs in the app, he gets successfully login on frontend (using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`), but the `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/` api returns 403 error . I investigated a little bit and found out we're getting this error in logs explorer.

> VPCSC_CHECK_FAILED : Access denied by organization restriction. Please
> contact your administrator for additional information.

Due to this, all the firebase rules (firestore, storage ..) which depends on `request.auth` are failing which is leading to user not able to use the website properly.

Note: This is mostly happening when user is using some kind of VPN

Comment: That error comes from VPC Service Controls. Do you have a service perimeter configured? https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview

Comment: @JohnHanley No we don't have it configured. It's set to the defaults that comes with firebase/google-cloud.

Comment: If you do not have an organization restriction, then I would open a Google Cloud support case. The error message says you do have one configured.

Comment: Project is not within any organization. Don't know if it matters or not. 
In that case, let me raise a support ticket for this